# Battery removal circuit via interruption

Tags: batteries, circuit-design

I am designing to detect battery removal with minimum current. I tried some designs that I expect interrupt when battery removal, but the port of my MCU was floating.  If I design like circuit in the attachment, Can I detect battery removal by interruption? still the port of mcu would be floating instead of grounding? Or do you have any suggestion design?

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. Is "MCU" the power pin or an I/O pin of the microcontroller? Is the battery in question actually providing power for the MCU? How do you intend to interrupt the CPU? Brownout detection? A change in a GPIO pin? What is the diode for?

Comment: MCU is I/O pin of microcontroller. Battey provides power for MCU but i did not draw the rest part of circuit. I just draw for battery removal circuit. I intend that when battery is removed, it will give low interrupt.

Comment: The MCU probably has also a built-in pull-down. Enable that pull down every 10s and read the logic input. You will see when the battery is removed.

Comment: @filo This assumes that the MCU can keep running for 10s after its power source is removed. That might require a large backup capacitor. I would suggest something more like every few milliseconds if minimizing power loss is critically important.

Comment: Is the question "how to safely shut down my application when the power dies?" ?

Comment: No. I have large backup capacitor. even if battery is removed, mcu is still working

Comment: You need to show us how the battery is related to the supply. What stops the supply backfeeding to the point labelled 'MCU' and keeping whatever detection you use at 3.3 V?

Answer (score 0):

If you you have battery and supercap directly connected, then there is no easy way to detect battery removal. But you can place a diode between battery and supercap, with cathode towards cap. Then you can measure battery removal at the diodes anode with a MCU pull down resistor enabled IO port.